# Make dual booting less of a hassle

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I was wondering if any of you have a simple guide to make this possible

- Ubuntu on separate disk
- Dual boot with windows 10
- Nice boot menu, something like burg with metro
- A non hassle way of uninstalling Ubuntu if I encounter problems

I tried this yesterday but couldn't get it to work, and i wont try again without some help. I would love to run Ubuntu, but at the moment just as a secondary OS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://askubuntu.com/questions/784775/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10-with-gpt. You have to be more specific, do you mean another device by separate disk? What did you try? What didn't work? Please explain.

Comment: Thats not the issue, I have managed to install ubuntu but i struglled with installing burg, no matter what i did the boot menu was still grub. thats my main problem anyways, i think i got the windows bootloader sorted with lilo or something

Comment: How about trying it out in VirtualBox to learn how to do it?

Comment: @user1603707: Wow, how did you manage to bring lilo into this?? Lilo is the *ancient* bootloader for linux. I don't think anybody is using that anymore. It was replaced by the evolved GRUB. If Burg is the problem, you should make a clear question about Burg.

Comment: No i could try that

Answer (score 0):

Well I personally enjoy using plop https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html it's fairly straightforward and any questions you may have would be on this site.